# Support uploading retina-resolution images and showing them at standard size

Tags: feature-request, images, editor, retina

This is a feature-request to support easily uploading retina-resolution (i.e. double resolution) images and automatically showing them at half-size.

It *is* currently possible to do this, but it takes a lot of tedious manual work.  Instead of using MarkDown, it's possible to use the `<img>` which allows resizing.

The following line

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/De4De.png" width="374">
```

will produce this:

[image]

While the image is `2*374 = 744` pixels wide, it's resized to 374 pixels on a standard screen and it's shown in high resolution on a retina screen.  I use this method often in my posts.

This is a feature request to automate this procedure.  For example, the image upload dialog could have a checkbox to indicate that an image should be inserted at half size:

[image]

On [Mathematica.SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) we have many users who use computers with retina screens and [this has come up before](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1259/12).  Some people are having difficulties with images being inserted at double size, others would simply like to be able to use high resolution images with relative ease.

---

If there are any existing non-official solutions, e.g. a userscript that automates this, please let me know!

Comment: Retina has come up a few times; is there a non brand name version of the term?

Comment: One thing to consider is that people coming from a mobile device, either from the app or browser, may prefer for lower resolution images to load for data usage concerns.

Comment: @JoeW That's just as good an argument against uploading any kind of image.  In general this would be an improvement for Mathematica.SE.  I don't use StackOverflow enough to comment on whether it would make sense there.

Comment: I would say its more in support of keeping images smaller in size which is something that is good practice anyway.